# Issue loading workspaces with VSCode on Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, workspace

Configuring VSCode - Insiders on Ubuntu-Mate 18.04 and running into a issue loading workspaces I have created. I can create the workspaces with specific folders, but when I attempt to 'load' that workspace, it just opens up the workspace file in VS and NOT load the workspace folders.

Tried doing a clean removal and install of VSCode. No luck.

I have a hunch that the file is seen as 'plain text' in caja and due to that, VS is just loading it in as a text file, not the actual workspace.

Is there a config that I need to edit for VScode that will load my workspaces properly?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
the solution is to save workspace as "*your_ws_name*.**code-workspace**".
"**.code-workspace**" as the extension.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add **.code-workspace** after your workspace file.